# Excel Filtering to New Sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

It has been a LONG time since I have used VBA and even then was not that great with it. What I have is a Master Log for every issue within the company which I work for. This is compiled of my data and my teammates data. Instead of trying to sort and filter manually and copy and paste into each customer report, I want Excel to automatically filter these out. I have already added a VLookup to assist when we add a new part number. Issue is the VBA Code I have been trying to use was from a "top rated" video on Youtube. Can someone please review and see where I made my mistake?

```
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()

Dim Splitcode As Range
Sheets("Corrective_Actions").Select
Set Splitcode = Range("Products")

For Each cell In Splitcode
Sheets("Corrective_Actions").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("Table5")
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Next cell
End Sub
```

Table in Picture is "Table 5"

[image]

Comment: What is the issue / error message?

Comment: Let's Start with... Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: On what line? Also, you are using values from two columns but only filtering the first column.

Comment: I think I have fixed the 1004 Error. Now I have a Run-Time Error 91 "Object Variable or with Block Variable not Set." ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData is the highlighted line.

Comment: GMalc, I have used the Vlookup function to autofill the data for "Brand" and "Type". With this, I want to carry all the data in the row with Customers "B", "V", and components onto separate WS. Then do the same with the CAR and NCRs on two other WS that are defined as NCRs and CARs. Did that answer your question?